# Workaround for ISSET when posting from form to same page

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to test whether a $_GET variable is set when a specific PHP page is visited:

I have a form which posts back to the same page (see below) below the form is PHP code to check whether the `product_id` variable is set and performs actions accordingly.

**FORM**

```
<form action="form_update_products.php" method="post" name="search" id="search">         
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="text-18">
                View / Update Product Barcodes by Product ID:
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <img src="images/spacer.png" width="100" height="4" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right">
                <input name="product_id" type="text" class="size-box" id="product_id"
                       onclick="this.value = '';" style="font-size: 22px; width:500px"/>
              </td>
              <td width="88%">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit-button"
                       id="submit" value="View Product Barcodes" />
</form>
```

**form_update_products.php**

```
<?php 

$product_id=$_POST['product_id'];

header('Location: update_products.php?id='.$product_id.'');

?>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
      {
        $product_id = $_GET['id'];
      }

      if (!isset($product_id))
      {
        echo '';
      }
      else { // output something }
```

For some reason the `$_GET['id']` variable always seems to default to the same `product_id` and only changes when entering a different `product_id` in the form. Even when closing the browser and opening the page afresh, the `$_GET['id']` variable is set.

Can anybody tell me why the `$_GET['id']` variable always seems to be set?

Comment: the url probably looks something like `www.example.com?id=12` the `$_GET` variable id equals 12 in this case.

Comment: @Bryan - the URL is blank when you first visit the page, so there is nothing to 'GET' - however by default the page displays information relating to the same product_id

Comment: please show your whole code for update_products.php, im sure theres a simple logic error somewhere, the funky isset/!isset conditional certainly hints at one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the id is always set you need to do a `empty()` check `empty()` does the same as `isset()` but will also check if something is entered

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
      $product_id = $_GET['id'];
      //your code
} else {
   echo '';
}
```

Comment: `empty()` fails bigtime if the value is `0` or any other value that php can typecast/convert into a false-y value. `empty(0)` is actually true.

Comment: you should also use `filter_input` function to filter user input. its a best practice.
here is detailed info in php manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php